# Use SSH when multiple Raspberries are connected to the router

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, raspberry-pi

So, I have multiple Raspberry Pi 4Bs (8) connected to my FritzBox via ethernet cables. All Pi's have SSH activated in their settings and are SSH-able within the local network by typing "ssh pi@ip.adress". I set up a dynDNS service for my router, so i can reach it without having to know the exact IP adress. That worked fine too.

Then I used the "Permit Access" option of the FritzBox to forward port 22 and 3389 to one of the RPi's. Now I can use SSH and MS Remote desktop on that one.

Problem: All the other RPi's have headless Raspberry OS Lite installations and I also need SSH from the Internet for them. But since the first RPi is already using port 22, i can't use any other RPi's with port 22.

There is a method called port-redirecting I read about multiple times in the internet. But noone really explained that one easily. So, i have to find a way to do this:

Router

|-> external port 2200 -> port 22 of Pi Nr. 0

|

|-> external port 2201 -> port 22 of Pi Nr. 1

|

|-> external port 2202 -> port 22 of Pi Nr. 2

|

|-> external port 2203 -> port 22 of Pi Nr. 3

But i have no idea how that works ;D

Which config file do I have to edit on the RPi's or which settings do I have to change on the router to achieve this?

Thank you for an answer :)

(PS: I am a networking noob. I have been coding java software for pc's and sometimes Discord Bots as a hobby for about 2 years now. But i have no idea how all that internet stuff works and i wanna learn it XD)

Comment: I might actually need a step by step explanation to how that stuff works, depending on how complex the solution is

Comment: to be sure, are you trying to connect through your IPv4 address, or through IPv6?

Comment: Port-redirects are another term for port-forwarding. On the router, you'd configure port forwarding for the external port on the WAN interface to the LAN interface's IP and port number [DNAT] _(this assumes your Pi's are configured with static IPs on the router - if they're not, either configure static IPs on the router or forward to MACs instead of IPs)_. It's recommended to forward high port numbers >`50000`, else you're going to get a lot of blocked requests from port scanners on the router _(it could be a few hundred to several thousand blocked attempts per day)_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There is a method called port-redirecting I read about multiple times in the internet. But noone really explained that one easily.

On most routers, allowing external access to an internal IPv4 host is literally the same function whether the port needs to be changed or not. If your Raspberry Pi has a private IP address, the router has to perform NAT anyway, so "port redirection" is part of it and isn't really a separate thing.

In your case, it seems that FRITZ!Box allows you to enter different "external" and "internal" ports if you select 'Other application' in the same "Permit Access" section.

Going by screenshots [found on google](https://www.edpnet.be/assets/images/support/img/installation-usage/internet/FB%20port%20sharing/fritz-portsharing-create-en.png) this would be:

- Application: [Other application]
- Protocol: [TCP]
- Port to device: [22] through [22]
- Port requested externally (IPv4): [**2201**]

*(The field is labelled as IPv4-specific because in IPv6 you would connect directly to the Pi's own address rather than the router's address, so there wouldn't be any separation between the "external" and "internal/to device" ports.)*

> Which config file do I have to edit on the RPi's or which settings do I have to change on the router to achieve this?

Normally it's one *or* the other, depending on what you want.

- ```
  Router
  |-> external port 2200 -> port 22 of Pi Nr. 0
  |-> external port 2201 -> port 22 of Pi Nr. 1
  |-> external port 2202 -> port 22 of Pi Nr. 2
  ```

  This is probably what you call "port redirection". It requires the router to translate the ports, and does not require any changes on the Pi itself.

  It is generally specific to IPv4; while still technically possible in IPv6 it's considered a "should be avoided" thing. (This is mostly because in IPv6 *each* of your Pi's would have *its own* external address, so the port-22 collision issue would be moot.)

  On FRITZ!Box, this seems to be hidden under the "Other application" option in the same "Permit Access" page that you're already using.
- ```
  Router
  |-> external port 2200 -> port 2200 of Pi Nr. 0
  |-> external port 2201 -> port 2201 of Pi Nr. 1
  |-> external port 2202 -> port 2202 of Pi Nr. 2
  ```

  This doesn't require any rewriting from the router (working the same in both IPv4 and IPv6), but requires the SSH service on the Pi to listen on the corresponding port.

  On Linux, that's the `Port` option in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` – you should probably add it twice, both for the default port 22 and for your custom port 2200.

You *could* of course do both, e.g. rewriting external port 2200 to the Pi port 3300, but that's just unnecessary.

There is also the option to *not* make the other Pi's accessible externally at all. Instead you could use `ssh -J` to connect to all of them through the 0th Pi, e.g. `ssh -J public.ip lan.ip.pi2`.

Comment: Thank you very much! That solved my problem :) It's actually very simple